# Liquid turn string into url link

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have the following code in a liquid template:

```
<a href="{{ sample.url }}">{{ sample.url }}</a>
```

Coming from jinja2 I was hoping for something [like this](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#urlize):

```
{{ sample.url|urlize }}
```

Does this exist in liquid?

Comment: You may want to consider a markdown interpreter with the option to automatically render urls as links?  (e.g. [redcarpet](https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet) with `autolink` extension turned on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen the liquid documentation and couldnt find any reference to that, but as the documentation sayed you can write your own filter to do that.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Programmers).